# QPolygon: How do I obtain the edges of the polygon

Tags: qt, qtgui

I am using QPolygon class. Is there any method which gives the edges of the respective polygon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by edges you mean the bounding box (smallest rectangle that encloses the polygon) then it's [`boundingRect()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qpolygon.html#boundingRect).

If you are talking about the edges that are made up of vertexes, then they are just lines in the polygon. `QPolygon` is just a `QVector<QPoint>` derived class. The edges are the lines constructed with consecutive `QPoints` in the list (plus the one from the last point to the first).